# Looking to parse the ECB FX rates from their xml feed

Tags: xml, parsing, lotus-notes, domparser

I am trying to parse the current exchange rates from the ECB website.
I currently have the following code:

```
Sub walkTree ( node As NotesDOMNode)
    %REM
        This function parses the xml feed to an object
        walkTree runs recursively, meaning that it is
        called only on an NotesDOMNode (a Node) rather than
        on the whole tree!
    %END REM
    Dim child As NotesDOMNode
    Dim elt As NotesDOMNode
    Dim attrs As NotesDOMNamedNodeMap
    Dim a As NotesDOMAttributeNode
    Dim piNode As NotesDOMProcessingInstructionNode
    LF = Chr(13)+Chr(10)

    If Not node.IsNull Then 'If note is not empty
        Select Case node.NodeType   'Switch through NodeType
            'DOMNODETYPE_DOCUMENT_NODE -> Walk child nodes
            'DOMNODETYPE_TEXT_NODE -> Parse text and return currency pare
            'DOMNODETYPE_ELEMENT_NODE -> Usually a node for currency, save the currency and the walk elements to get fx price

        Case DOMNODETYPE_DOCUMENT_NODE:        ' If it is a Document node
            'domParser.Output( "Document node: "+node.Nodename )
            'Set child = node.FirstChild   ' Get the first node
            Dim numChildNodes As Integer
            numChildNodes = node.NumberOfChildNodes
            'domParser.Output(" has "+Cstr(numChildNodes)+" Child Nodes"+LF)

            'Walk child nodes
            While numChildNodes > 0
                If child Is Nothing Then
                    Set child = node.FirstChild   ' Get the first node
                Else
                    Set child = child.NextSibling ' Get next node
                End If
                numChildNodes = numChildNodes - 1
                Call walkTree(child) 'Recursively call this same function on child nodes
            Wend

        Case DOMNODETYPE_DOCUMENTTYPE_NODE:   ' It is a <!DOCTYPE> tag
            'domParser.Output("Document Type node: "+ node.NodeName+LF)

        Case DOMNODETYPE_TEXT_NODE:           ' Plain text node
            'Den Case auskommentieren
            If node.Parentnode.Nodename = "Cube" Or node.Parentnode.Nodename = "Cube time" Then
                'MsgBox CStr(node.NodeValue)
                domParser.Output(node.NodeValue + "##")
            End If

        Case DOMNODETYPE_ELEMENT_NODE:

            If node.NodeName = "Cube" Then 'Müsste heissen "Cube"
                Dim numAttr As Integer
                numAttr = node.Attributes.Numberofentries
                Dim aNode As NotesDOMAttributeNode
                Dim bNode As NotesDOMAttributeNode
                Dim copy As NotesDOMNode
                Set copy = node.Firstchild

                ' Setze attr =  node.Attributes
                ' Zähl die anzahl der Attribute
                ' Wenn es keine hat, dann mache nichts
                ' Wenn es mehr als 0 hat, dann speichere attr(0) und attr(1) in einem array
                ' gebe das array in diesem Sub zurück
                ' parse das array so, dass es im Format CHF/CHF##1.0000; zurückkommt
                domParser.Output(node.NodeValue + "~~")
            End If


            Set elt = node
            Dim numChildren As Integer
            numChildren =  elt.NumberOfChildNodes
            Set child = elt.FirstChild     ' Get child
            While numChildren > 0
                Call walkTree(child)
                Set child = child.NextSibling   ' Get next child
                numChildren = numChildren - 1
            Wend

        Case Else:
            'domParser.Output("Ignoring node: "+Cstr(node.NodeType)+LF)

    End Select  'node.NodeType
    End If        'Not node.IsNull
End Sub
```

The problem in my code is that it doesn't really parse through the rates. It saves empty values. I am not super familiar with Lotus Notes DomParser and it's getting increasingly difficult for me to find the error.

Today's output should look like this:

```
CHF/CHF#1.00;USD/CHF#(1.1008/1.1026);GBP/CHF#(1.1008/0.78243);EUR/CHF#1.1008;CNY/CHF#(1.1008/7.1909);
```

Where the brackets should already be the calculated result with 4 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely a guess, but when using the NotesDOMParser you have to be careful about what I call "phantom nodes", which are basically empty nodes where you don't expect to find them. I see that your code is checking `is Nothing`, but my experience is that that's not always enough. You may also need to be checking `isNull()`. At least, thats what I've always done in the code that I use.

I wrote my own utilty functions to process DOM data in an idiom that should be easy and familiar to all Notes/Domino programmers. You can find them here for comparison against your code.

- [Page 1: getFirstElement, getNthElement, getElementText, setTextItemFrom Element, setRichTextItemFromElement](http://http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/PowerOfTheSchwartz.nsf/htdocs/lsxmldom1.htm)
- [Page 2: getElementAttributeText, setTextItemFromElementAttribute, setRichTextItemFormElementAttribute](https://web.archive.org/web/20210314175143/http://www.poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/htdocs/lsxmldom2.htm)

Comment: do I not check for IsNull in the first IF? thanks for the links, I will read through them!

Comment: I didn't notice the isNull in the first If statement. It's just a little hard to follow your code. I've tried in my utility functions to keep things very concise, but I'm not trying to do a full recursive walk of the tree.

Comment: I will check them out, the code is a mess I agree. I haven't coded it, I inherited it and now need to check for something that seems difficult to implement in the current structure.
One thing you mentioned is definitely true: The node values seem to be empty and that is causing a problem.